# How can I use Dropbox as a host for uploaded files using PHP?

Tags: php, hosting, dropbox

So I am working on a small website with some simple admin area. In the admin area it should be possible to upload/download/update files of a global directory. The problem is that my php programs don't have write permission to the server and the size limit of the database is 100mb which is not enough. Therefore I thought it would be nice to store the files in a dedicated Dropbox account or something.

My questions are:

- Would it be reasonably easy to code a web-interface to this Dropbox account in PHP?
- Are there any alternatives to Dropbox for this purpose?
- Any other ideas how to handle this situation?

Edit: My problem with Dropbox is that it's API uses OAuth. But since I want to connect to one global account for all users instead of each users account this seems inappropriate and I don't even know if the authentication is possible this way. All the links mentioned use this API and therefore need user authentication through a redirect.

Comment: switch to a different webhost that isn't so restrictive?

Comment: since this is a small university website the free university hosting has to be good enough

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the dropbox account. Try out the [PhpDropboxUploader](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/PHPDropboxUploader). Its also mentioned in the [dropbox Wiki](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/PHP_Dropbox_Uploader)

```
require 'DropboxUploader.php';

$uploader = new DropboxUploader('email.address.used.to.log.in.to.dropbox@example.com', 'dropbox-password');
$uploader->upload('file-to-be-uploaded', 'destination-folder-in-dropbox');
```

Comment: Hmm I the mentioned link doesn't work for me. And when I google the PhpDropboxUploader it tells me that I should the API instead because the library only scrapes the dropbox website. I think my problem with the API is that it uses OAuth for authentication which isn't designed for a simple authentication with known credentials.

Answer (score 1):

for your first question, there is indeed a PHP SDK that is not official but still listed on dropbox site :
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk
and 
https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox

btw, are you sure you can't make a directory for which PHP has write permission ?

Comment: Thanks for the link! Since it is an university server I can't and even if I could the size limit would be 100MB.